# How to change password expiration prompt?

Tags: linux, password

I create accounts for some users on the server running Ubuntu 16.04/18.04. Users receive emails for a default temporary password. They are forced to change password on the first log in.

How can I configure the password expiration prompt? The current prompt is:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Enter login(LDAP) password:
```

I think it is confusing. Users may think the default password is wrong because of the warning message. I want it to be something else like:

```
WARNING: Your temporary password has expired.
You must now enter a NEW password and login again.
Enter NEW login password:
```

Conclusion:
The prompt is not configurable. It is hard coded in pam_ldap [here](https://github.com/PADL/pam_ldap/blob/6082484b2b85626f31e998557323503cd03de32f/pam_ldap.h#L270).

Comment: What distribution is this? How has login been configured? And keep in mind that this prompt is asking for the _old_ password, not the new one.

Comment: How has login been configured?

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 16.04/18.04. What do you mean by 'how has login been configured'?

Comment: `Enter login(LDAP) password` is not the normal Ubuntu password or change of password prompt. Someone has reconfigured the system already. What was done to it?

Comment: I deployed OpenLDAP on the server. I don't think I changed any configuration to change the prompt.

Comment: Nobody configured the server to authenticate against an LDAP server? It's important to get this right, because if you really want to change the password prompts, you will have to recompile some software. These are hard coded. But _which_ software depends on exactly where this message is coming from.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I installed several packages to the client and specified the LDAP server when configuraing ldap-auth-config. I mean I did not change the default prompt after an LDAP server is added to authentication. If I have to rebuild packages to change the hard-coded prompt, I think I will leave it there as it is.

Comment: I find the prompt in pam_ldap source code [here](https://github.com/PADL/pam_ldap/blob/6082484b2b85626f31e998557323503cd03de32f/pam_ldap.h#L270). It is hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pam_ldap. What profiles are listed and enabled when you run `pam-auth-update`? Also have a look at ubuntu's [LDAPClientAuthentication documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication).

Comment: You are right. I find it in the pam_ldap source code [here](https://github.com/PADL/pam_ldap/blob/6082484b2b85626f31e998557323503cd03de32f/pam_ldap.h#L270).